# C program doesn't fully execute when scanf() calls are swapped

Tags: c, scanf

This program doesn't allow me to enter an operation and goes straight to the default case in the switch, printing `"Error!!"`:

```
printf("Enter two integers: \n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
system("cls");
printf("Enter an operation :  ");
scanf("%c",&op);

switch(op)
{
    case '+': printf("%d+%d=%d\n",a,b,a+b); break;
    case '*': printf("%d*%d=%d\n",a,b,a*b); break;
    case '-': printf("%d-%d=%d\n",a,b,a-b); break;
    case '/': printf("%d/%d=%d\n",a,b,a/b); break;
    default: printf("Error!! \a \n");
}
return 0;
```

However, when I put the printf statement of "Enter an operation" before that of "Enter the two integers" below, the program runs smoothly.  Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong in the first program?

```
printf("Enter an operation :  ");
scanf("%c",&op);
printf("Enter two integers: \n");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
system("cls");


switch(op)
{
    case '+': printf("%d+%d=%d\n",a,b,a+b); break;
    case '*': printf("%d*%d=%d\n",a,b,a*b); break;
    case '-': printf("%d-%d=%d\n",a,b,a-b); break;
    case '/': printf("%d/%d=%d\n",a,b,a/b); break;
    default: printf("Error!! \a \n");
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanx! That's all I needed to do... Sometimes it's the little things you don't pay attention to.

Comment: `scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);` ...`scanf("%c",&op);` will be consumed in the %c newline that has not been consumed in the `%d`. change to `scanf(" %c",&op);`, then Preceding blank characters are skipped.

Comment: just change `scanf("%c",&op);` to `scanf(" %c",&op);` .

Comment: this line: scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);  how is scanf to determine when one string stops and the next begins.  suggest: scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);

Comment: this line: case '/': printf("%d/%d=%d\n",a,b,a/b); break; is using an integer divide, so will give 0 when a is < b

Comment: the call(s) scanf() should check the return value to assure that the parameters have all been set from the input.  This would have caught the problems with the format strings being used in the scanf() calls

Answer (score 2):

If you add a

```
printf("%d\n", op)
```

immediately after the `scanf("%c", &op);` in the first version, you'll see that `op` has a value of 10 or 14.  That's a `\n` (newline) or `\r` (carriage return).

An [explanation for that behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx) is:

> White-space characters that are ordinarily skipped are read when **c** is specified.

To ignore the CR/NL after the second number, change `scanf("%c", &op);` to

```
scanf(" %c", &op);
```

Comment: And most importantly, *always* test the result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) -the number of successfully read items- and read the documentation of every function that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line of code:

```
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
```

If you compile and run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("a:%d b:%d\n", a, b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How do we set `a` to `1` and `b` to `2`? If I type in `12`, then I get `12` for `a` and `0` for `b`. I think you are missing whitespace between the two format specifiers.

Comment: Umm, if you type 12, the scanf will not return (unless you cause end-of-file or parse failure), because it wants input for two `%d`. If `scanf` does return, it will return 1 and `b` will be left uninitialized and you have UB if you use it. Also `%d` will eat all preceding whitespace, no use putting one before or between the two `%d`